# "java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems" during execution Selenium tests with TestNG using Maven

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using Selenium with TestNG for automated testing. I am using Maven as a software project management and comprehension tool. I have all maven dependencies in my class path. Still I got Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:

The import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver cannot be resolved.selenium.firefox.driver jar is present in my class path same problem for other dependencies.

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Do you see a section of maven dependencies in your project?

Answer (score 1):

**Try these steps:**

1. Right click the project
2. Goto `Maven` Menu
3. Click the `Update Project Configuration`

Comment: If my solution helps you mean then make it as answer. It will help future readers.

Comment: @Manigandan, I have exactly the same problem as OP, but your solution didn't help. Could you advise anything else? What could be a problem?